# Splitting into time buckets when grouping by name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection, division_entry.

I wish to filter by label, and then bucket by time and by distinct values of unique.
Finally I want all the distinct values of unique in given time span.

Presently, I have to bucket in the code and make a call per time span. This leads to too many calls.
Present -

> db.division_entry.aggregate([{ $match : { $and : [ { "division.label" :
>   "ABCD"}, { "timestamp" :  { $gt: 1495448249635, $lt: 1495448249641 } }
>   ] }  } , {$group : { _id : "$unique"} } , {$count : "value" }])

Help for the actual result is much appreciated.

Edit:
More details:

```
{
            "_id" : "1",
            "timestamp" : NumberLong("1495448249640"),
            "unique" : "One",
            "division" : [
                    {
                            "label" : "ABCD"
                    }
            ]
    }
    {
            "_id" : "3",
            "timestamp" : NumberLong("1495448249636"),
            "unique" : "Two",
            "division" : [
                    {
                            "label" : "ABCD"
                    }
            ]
    }
    {
            "_id" : "2",
            "timestamp" : NumberLong("1495448249650"),
            "unique" : "Two",
            "division" : [
                    {
                            "label" : "ABCD"
                    }
            ]
    }

db.division_entry.aggregate([{ $match : { $and : [ { "division.label": "ABCD"}, { "timestamp" : { $gt: 1495448249635, $lt: 1495448249651 }} ] } } , {$group : { _id : "$unique"} }])
         { "_id" : "Two" }
         { "_id" : "One" }

db.division_entry.aggregate([{ $match : { $and : [ { "division.label" : "ABCD"}, { "timestamp" : { $gt: 1495448249635, $lt: 1495448249651 } } ] } } , {$group : { _id : "$unique"} } , {$count : "value" }])
        { "value" : 2 }
```

This is done for a specific time range, which has been specified in the match query. Say I want a minute's granularity for a day's data, I will have to make 1440 such calls, where in each call the timestamp range will cover a minute.

I wanted help to bucket and find distinct values for the field "unique" simultaneously.

Comment: What is the actual grouping here? Should you be seeing the distinct `"timestamp"` as well or is it just the `"unique"` values distinct within "timestamp buckets"? It's a bit hard to tell from your question and with such a small sample. There are a couple of techniques to this and it does not help that your included aggregation pipeline example is not valid. If you could edit to clarify those points, and preferably with expected output, then it would help your question.

Comment: If you could specify that your "buckets" are something really simple such as a "regular interval" ( i.e 1minute, 1 hour, etc ) then that also makes things a lot clearer. Your included queried timestamps are only 6ms apart, which probably does not really indicate what you are trying to do.

Comment: Much better. So the interval is always uniform? By that I mean for example 1 minute between all documents in the grouping? Of course giving the option to change that interval, but a consistent interval between grouped results is desired.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, the boundaries are at a regular interval, say, 1 minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a regular interval the best thing to do is perform some "date math" to round out the current `"timestamp"` values in the document to a common interval value for grouping. The best way to do this is using the standard match of subtracting the modulus ( remainder ) as applied to the milliseconds value of the interval required.

In the aggregation framework we supply using [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) and [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) to form party of the compound key along with the current documents `"unique"` field value in the `_id` key to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```js
db.division_entry.aggregate([
  // Sanely restrict to a range of dates to analyse - here is one day
  { "$match": { 
    "timestamp": { "$gte": 1495670400000, "$lt": 1495756800000 }
  }},

  // Group by interval - example of 1 hour ( 1000ms * 60sec * 60min )
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "time": {
        "$subtract": [
          "$timestamp",
          { "$mod": [ "$timestamp", ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) ] }
        ]
      },
      "unique": "$unique"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

Thus for different intervals, all you need to is supply the math for the interval required:

- 1 minute ( 1000 * 60 )
- 1 hour ( 1000 * 60 * 60 )
- 1 day ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 )

---

Just for reference, there is a newly introduced [`$bucket`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) operator, but it's purpose is rather for "cut points" that are **not** uniform. ie 0-5 minutes, 6-20 minutes, 20 - 50 minutes and over 50 minutes as an example use case.

For anything "uniform", a math based approach is the most efficient to implement.

Comment: How would you go about implementing $subtract in Java? The official documentation mentions just building the document yourself and I an looking for a more code-based/quicker solution

Comment: @MonsieurBeilto It depends in the implementation. You can always [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) or simply search for existing answers that are likely already here ( I probably have written some of them ). At it's core that all BSON is basically either a `Document` or a standard Java `List`.

Answer (score 0):

This is based/inspired from Neil's answer.

What I additionally wanted were the different time intervals and the number of unique uuids in them. The answer he provided gives, for each unique uuid, the number of times it occurs in a time interval, which was in the q.

```
db.divisive_entry.aggregate([
  { "$match": { 
    "timestamp": { "$gte": 1395448852351, "$lt": 1497428775000 }
  }},

  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "time": {
        "$subtract": [
          "$timestamp",
          { "$mod": [ "$timestamp", ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) ] }
        ]
      },
      "unique": "$unique"
    },
  }},

  { "$group": 
    {
        "_id": "$_id.time",
        "count" : { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: You could have simply left a comment clarifying that difference, and nothing in your question suggests that this is the case. Also this is not a "threaded discussion" but rather one question and a definitive answer. If it's the "count of distinct unique" for each time period that you want, then a second grouping is indeed the way to do it. Next time you ask a question though, you should comment to clarify to the person who answered, rather than leaving them hanging there.